# Avoid parent folder structure when creating tar

Tags: go, tar, directory-structure

https://github.com/mimoo/eureka/blob/master/folders.go

I am using the compress method given in the above link for creating Tar with recursive folder structure in Golang.

Now, say if I give `/home/Documents/project` as src

Then, the created tar also contains /home/Documents/project/`files`
I want to avoid the parent folder structure here.

Ex. tar should directly contain : `files`

How can I modify this method to achieve this ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tricky method without modifying the code, If your program **does not have concurrent logic**, you can do this:

```golang
os.Chdir("/home/Documents/project")
compress("./", output)
```